# How to limit a variable search to a single line of text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Considering this sample text:

```
grupo1, tiago1A, bola1A, mola1A, tijolo1A, pedro1B, bola1B, mola1B, tijolo1B, raimundo1C, bola1C, mola1C, tijolo1C, joao1D, bola1D, mola1D, tijolo1D, felipe1E, bola1E, mola1E, tijolo1E,

grupo2, tiago2A, bola2A, mola2A, tijolo2A, pedro2B, bola2B, mola2B, tijolo2B, raimundo2C, bola2C, mola2C, tijolo2C, joao2D, bola2D, mola2D, tijolo2D, felipe2E, bola2E, mola2E, tijolo2E,

grupo3, tiago3A, bola3A, mola3A, tijolo3A, pedro3B, bola3B, mola3B, tijolo3B, raimundo3C, bola3C, mola3C, tijolo3C, joao3D, bola3D, mola3D, tijolo3D, felipe3E, bola3E, mola3E, tijolo3E,

grupo4, tiago4A, bola4A, mola4A, tijolo4A, pedro4B, bola4B, mola4B, tijolo4B, raimundo4C, bola4C, mola4C, tijolo4C, joao4D, bola4D, mola4D, tijolo4D, felipe4E, bola4E, mola4E, tijolo4E,

grupo5, tiago5A, bola5A, mola5A, tijolo5A, pedro5B, bola5B, mola5B, tijolo5B, raimundo5C, bola5C, mola5C, tijolo5C, joao5D, bola5D, mola5D, tijolo5D, felipe5E, bola5E, mola5E, tijolo5E,
```

I would like to capture the 20 values that follow `grupo3` and store them in groups of 4.

I am using this: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JesAbc/2))

```
/grupo3,((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)),/
```

but this only returns the first 4 comma separated values after `grupo3`.

I need generate this array structure:

```
Match 1 
Group 1 tiago3A 
Group 2 bola3A
Group 3 mola3A
Group 4 tijolo3A

Match 2 
Group 1 pedro3B
Group 2 bola3B
Group 3 mola3B
Group 4 tijolo3B

Match 3 
Group 1 raimundo3C
Group 2 bola3C
Group 3 mola3C
Group 4 tijolo3C

Match 4 
Group 1 joao3D
Group 2 bola3D
Group 3 mola3D
Group 4 tijolo3D

Match 5
Group 1 felipe3E
Group 2 bola3E
Group 3 mola3E
Group 4 tijolo3E
```

Comment: Why do you have space before `*` in your regexp in the question, but not in the demo?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you did it on regex101, where you put `grupo3` at the beginning of the regular expression?

Comment: @Makyen Okay I've disambiguated the question.  I'll notify the answers to update their work if the question no longer requires further editing.

Comment: @AntonioOliveira Your input data has been edited. `tijolo raimundo` was changed to `tijolo, raimundo` on multiple lines. It was assumed by the editor that this was an error, not intentional. If this was an intentional part of your input data, please either tell us that is the case, or [edit] the question to return the data to what you actually desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

`/,(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),.*?$/m`

the `/m` in the end indicates the flag for `multi-line` and `$` before that indicates `end of line`. [`Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Imoozr/1)

**Edit:** For getting every 4 elements only form the 3rd paragraph

```
/grupo3,((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)),/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NQRGWt/1)

And you can get the desired output in PHP like:

```
preg_match('/grupo3,((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)), ((.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)),/', $str, $matches);

$groups = [];
unset($matches[0]);
$matches = array_values($matches);
$count = count($matches);
$j=0;
for($i=1;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if($i%5 == 0)
    {
        $j++;
        continue;
    }
    $groups[$j][] = $matches[$i];

}

var_dump($groups);
```

Output will be something like:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string ' tiago3A' (length=8)
      1 => string ' bola3A' (length=7)
      2 => string ' mola3A' (length=7)
      3 => string ' tijolo3A' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'pedro3B' (length=7)
      1 => string ' bola3B' (length=7)
      2 => string ' mola3B' (length=7)
      3 => string ' tijolo3B' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'raimundo3C' (length=10)
      1 => string ' bola3C' (length=7)
      2 => string ' mola3C' (length=7)
      3 => string ' tijolo3C' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'joao3D' (length=6)
      1 => string ' bola3D' (length=7)
      2 => string ' mola3D' (length=7)
      3 => string ' tijolo3D' (length=9)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'felipe3E' (length=8)
      1 => string ' bola3E' (length=7)
      2 => string ' mola3E' (length=7)
      3 => string 'tijolo3E' (length=0)
```

Comment: See what I posted. I do not want the four initial elements of each paragraph. I want to group the four elements (LIMITED TO PARAGRAPH 3) into 5 subgroups.

Comment: @mega6382. Basically that. But how to tell php that the first element of the parentheses is of the same group of the second ((? P <name>. *?), ..) ((? P <name>) ...)?

Comment: In an attempt to rescue this page, I've had to edit the OP's question to disambiguate the input data and the desired result.  You may want to update your answer to align with the new data.  (Your method can stay the same, it is only the values that have changed.)  ... oh and I added some missing commas in the input, so your output array will be complete if you rerun your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive the lateness of this answer.  This is the comprehensive answer with a clean/direct solution that I would have posted earlier if this page wasn't put on hold.  This is as refined a solution as I can devise without knowing more about how your input data is generated/accessed.

The input:

```
$text='grupo1, tiago1A, bola1A, mola1A, tijolo1A, pedro1B, bola1B, mola1B, tijolo1B, raimundo1C, bola1C, mola1C, tijolo1C, joao1D, bola1D, mola1D, tijolo1D, felipe1E, bola1E, mola1E, tijolo1E,

grupo2, tiago2A, bola2A, mola2A, tijolo2A, pedro2B, bola2B, mola2B, tijolo2B, raimundo2C, bola2C, mola2C, tijolo2C, joao2D, bola2D, mola2D, tijolo2D, felipe2E, bola2E, mola2E, tijolo2E,

grupo3, tiago3A, bola3A, mola3A, tijolo3A, pedro3B, bola3B, mola3B, tijolo3B, raimundo3C, bola3C, mola3C, tijolo3C, joao3D, bola3D, mola3D, tijolo3D, felipe3E, bola3E, mola3E, tijolo3E,

grupo4, tiago4A, bola4A, mola4A, tijolo4A, pedro4B, bola4B, mola4B, tijolo4B, raimundo4C, bola4C, mola4C, tijolo4C, joao4D, bola4D, mola4D, tijolo4D, felipe4E, bola4E, mola4E, tijolo4E,

grupo5, tiago5A, bola5A, mola5A, tijolo5A, pedro5B, bola5B, mola5B, tijolo5B, raimundo5C, bola5C, mola5C, tijolo5C, joao5D, bola5D, mola5D, tijolo5D, felipe5E, bola5E, mola5E, tijolo5E,';
```

The method: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b391209dcd09f840740479a1644d40db087351c5))

```
var_export(preg_match('/^grupo3, \K.*(?=,)/m',$text,$out)?array_chunk(explode(', ',$out[0]),4):'fail');
```

Use `preg_match()` to extract the single line, then use `explode()` to split the string on "comma space", then use `array_chunk()` to store in an array of 5 subarrays containing 4 elements each.

The pattern targets `grupo3,` at the start of the line, then restarts the full match using `\K` then greedily matches every non-newline character and stops just before the last comma in the line.  The positive lookahead `(?=,)` doesn't store the final comma in the full string match.

([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JesAbc/4))

My method does not retain any leading and trailing spaces, just the values themselves.

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tiago3A',
    1 => 'bola3A',
    2 => 'mola3A',
    3 => 'tijolo3A',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'pedro3B',
    1 => 'bola3B',
    2 => 'mola3B',
    3 => 'tijolo3B',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'raimundo3C',
    1 => 'bola3C',
    2 => 'mola3C',
    3 => 'tijolo3C',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'joao3D',
    1 => 'bola3D',
    2 => 'mola3D',
    3 => 'tijolo3D',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'felipe3E',
    1 => 'bola3E',
    2 => 'mola3E',
    3 => 'tijolo3E',
  ),
)
```

p.s. If the search term (`$needle`) is to be dynamic, you can use something like this to achieve the same result: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3e389ed69682a3c9d1d19109750998b18cb77fa))

```
$needle='grupo3';
// if the needle may include any regex-sensitive characters, use preg_quote($needle,'/') at $needle
var_export(preg_match('/^'.$needle.', \K.*(?=,)/m',$text,$out)?array_chunk(explode(', ',$out[0]),4):'fail');

/* or this is equivalent...
    if(preg_match('/^'.$needle.', \K.*(?=,)/m',$text,$out)){
        $singles=explode(', ',$out[0]);
        $groups=array_chunk($singles,4);
        var_export($groups);
    }else{
        echo 'fail';
    }
*/
```

Comment: @AntonioOliveira I'm sorry, I had to hijack your question content to rescue it from being locked down.  Now that it is opened, I've provided a couple of refined solutions for your question.  If you have any questions about the techniques, just ask.